# How can I define an entity such as nbsp in an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, html-entities

I have an asp.net application that renders and works correctly in all browsers. However when checking with the validator at http://validator.w3.org/ I get the following error:

```
reference to undeclared general entity nbsp
```

The Error is also keeping me from being able to use loadstorm to test the application. Loadstorm gives me this error:

```
Entity 'nbsp' not defined
```

changing each "nbsp" to "#160" is not an option because they are coming from a ckeditor that users enter content into

I have also tried doing something like the following on the page, but it doesn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;"> ]>
```

should I be trying to declare it somewhere else or be doing something entirely different all together?

Comment: Surely you're sanitizing the input from ckeditor anyway, aren't you? Can't you convert &nbsp; to &#160; or an actual non-breaking space character at that point?

Answer (score 0):

Your page is probably missing the XHTML `DOCTYPE` declaration. Assuming you are going to output an XHTML 1.0 transitional markup, please add the following before everything else on your XHTML output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```